# Good reference on the algebraic geometry of non-associative rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, non-associative-algebras

I am looking for a good reference about the algebraic geometry of non-associative rings. I am in particular interested in derivation algebras.

Preferrably an online resource or a book that is available online, since every library near me is in lockdown right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See "Seven Lectures on the Universal Algebraic Geometry" by 
Boris Plotkin (Hebrew University). The text is in arXiv. Since the OP does not explain what "algebraic geometry" means, here are some explanations. The point is that there are several statements in the classical algebraic geometry which make sense and are even true in much more general situations. This was first discovered by Remeslennikov for groups, Guba, Makanin and Razborov for their theory of equations over free groups and then by Kharlampovich and Myasnikov and ( less explicitly) by Sela for the Tarski problem.  More recently some of the theory applied to free associative ring. Plotkin suggests a much more general approach which can be applied to general algebraic systems including  nonassociative rings.

Comment: [Plotkin - 7 lectures on the universal algebraic geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204245).

Comment: [Remeslennikov - Algebraic geometry over algebraic structures](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Remeslennikov&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=Algebraic+geometry+over+algebraic+structures) (8 results on MSN).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/355418) by **user6976**, there is the idea of development of algebraic geometry to (essentialy) *any* general algebraic system. This is carried out(following Plotkin's work) by E. Daniyarova, A. Miasnikov, V. Remeslennikov and co-authors in a series of papers.

A more recent survey (2016) of this area, called *Universal Algebraic Geometry*, of which (not necessarily associative) algebras is naturally of central interest, is Artem N. Shevlyakov's [Lectures notes in universal algebraic geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02743).

This survey is very easy to read, and has a very good bibliography ponting out to more specific topics.